# Why is my prompt reprint on horizontal ConEmu resize?

Tags: conemu, clink

I've observed a weird behavior in my ConEmu shell:

When i resize HORIZONTALLY the ConEmu window, and clink is enabled, after finishing the resize the shell prompt is being printed again:

Before: [image]

After: [image]

It is really annoying and occurs on every resize like operation, e.g. spliting,
moving splits..

In my bootup batch i use the following code to set the prompt (same as the default cmd task of conemu):

```
::
:: Form the command prompt
::
:: This will start prompt with `User@PC `
set ConEmuPrompt0=$E[32m$E]9;8;"USERNAME"$E\@$E]9;8;"COMPUTERNAME"$E\$S

:: Followed by colored `Path`
set ConEmuPrompt1=%ConEmuPrompt0%$E[92m$P$E[90m
if NOT "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "AMD64" (
  if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%" == "AMD64" if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" (
    rem Use another text color if cmd was run from SysWow64
    set ConEmuPrompt1=%ConEmuPrompt0%$E[93m$P$E[90m
  )
)

:: Carriage return and `$` or `>`
:: Spare `$E[90m` was specially added because of GitShowBranch.cmd
if "%ConEmuIsAdmin%" == "ADMIN" (
  set ConEmuPrompt2=$_$E[90m$$
) else (
  set ConEmuPrompt2=$_$E[90m$G
)

:: Finally reset color and add space
set ConEmuPrompt3=$E[m$S$E[0m

:: Set the prompt
prompt %ConEmuPrompt1%%ConEmuPrompt2%%ConEmuPrompt3%
```

So far my observations are:
1. Problem occurs only when clink is injected
2. Problem occurs only when also the prompt has a newline character.

I suppose that on resize clink erases and reprints the prompt somehow incorrectly. The problem can be easily reproduced on a vanilla ConEmu by enabling the clink feature, and trying to resize the window horizontally.

I am just a little step away from my perfect windows shell...
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT1: Just confirmed by testing it in Console2 that its a clink issue.

Comment: Report an issue to clink author.

Comment: Just tried it with Console2, you are right, its a clink problem.